# Change image src on the button when hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change my img src when I hover on the button.

There are few answers that are similar to mine,

but I still can't figure it out.

```
<button class='Nav' id="Nav_Homepage">
    <img src="./img/Homepage.png" class='img_Nav' id="img_Homepage">
    <label class='lb_Nav'> Homepage </label>
</button>
```

Comment: you may need javascript to accomplish this

Comment: Best way is to achieve using CSS rather than using JS. Thats how seasoned developer thinks.

Comment: @Nirus you are right, but in my humble knowledge I cannot think of a solution where one would change image src with css only. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: it could be done if you're using the image as a background though

Comment: @Chris i totally agree with you. But imo i would suggest the OP to change the logic to follow a best possible way rather than sticking with what OP needs when there is best way to achieve the same.

Comment: @Nirus thanks for being caring

Comment: @Chris WC. Happy to help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using CSS

```css
#Nav_Homepage span {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff.png&text=P) no-repeat;
  width: 20px;  /* your image width */
  height: 20px; /* your image height */
  display: inline-block;
}
#Nav_Homepage label {
  display: inline-block;
}
#Nav_Homepage:hover span {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/20x20/ff0000/ffffff.png&text=H) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button class='Nav' id="Nav_Homepage">
    <span class='img_Nav'></span>
    <label class='lb_Nav'> Homepage </label>
</button>
```

Comment: Thx! It worked by just using CSS!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the main difference between property "background" and "background-image"?

Comment: @Lee if you use `background-image` then you have to used `background-repeat`, `background-position` separate if you don't use exact size image which you are using in `width` & `height` tag

Answer (score 6):

if you have new image source just use this code. use this method if you want change image with more than one images.

```
$('#btn_id')

.on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#img_Homepage').attr('src', 'url_of_new_image');
})

.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#img_Homepage').attr('src', 'url_of_old_image');
});
```

Comment: Thx! This works as well, but I prefer using CSS. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Nav_Homepage").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children('img').attr("src", "./img/newimage.png");
  });
  $("#Nav_Homepage").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children('img').attr("src", "./img/Homepage.png");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='Nav' id="Nav_Homepage">
    <img src="./img/Homepage.png" class='img_Nav' id="img_Homepage">
    <label class='lb_Nav'> Homepage </label>
</button>
```

Comment: This has 2 issues, **first** `$(this)` refers to `#Nav_Homepage` which is the button here not the image in it.  **Second** you are only changing the image `src` on `mousover` and not changing it back to the original image when the mouse leaves

Comment: Thanks! Have updated the code.